# How can i get utc time in Java Script, which is not dependent on client system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, momentjs, utc

In moment.js

```
moment().utc()
moment()
```

In this both case i get Client side time.
I have a problem when users change their time. For example if users clock is 2 hour ahead or behind.

I am trying to create a timer in JS which should not be dependent on client side time.

Any solutions?

Comment: You're running the code on the client, therefore you will get the client time. Run the code on your server and you will get the server time instead. You haven't given enough information about the context of how you're using this code to provide any kind of detailed answer. Please update your questions with more details about how this code is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you edit your system time but not your system timezone, so it's obvius that utc time change too.

If your scope is to create a timer you can use `moment-timer`. It is a plugin for moment duration. This script is indipendent from system time.

Here there is the [documentation](https://github.com/SeverinDK/moment-timer)

and here an example:

```js
console.log('start the timer');
const timer = moment.duration(5, 'seconds').timer({
  loop: true
}, function() {
  console.log('End timer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment-timer/lib/moment-timer.js"></script>
```